# Angular DOM elements are not showing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web

Hi I am using an UI Library (forced to, company issue..) which provides an Angular component, which renders a form.

Now I want to disable all of the input fields an buttons inside this form. But the component of the library doesn't provide me the possibility to pass a parameter to change the status to read only.

Now I have no other option to do dirty DOM hacking. However it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my HTML of my own component, where I render the Library Component:

```
<component-of-the-library #formComponent></component-of-the-library>
```

Now inside my own components class I reference it:

```
@ViewChild('formComponent', {read: ElementRef}) formComponent: ElementRef;
```

However when I use the nativeElement feature and the querySelectorAll() function I don't see the button elements:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {                
  console.log(this.formComponent.nativeElement);
 console.log(this.formComponent.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('button'))
}
```

The first line outputs the DOM of the library component. There I also see the buttons.

However the second line just returns an empty NodeList.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I can't see why your approach would not work - however, given that it is not working have you tried using jQuery or renderer2 (Ive never tried the latter) ... https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2 ... something like $(this.formComponent.nativeElement).find("button")

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all these, come up with a div overlay and with the size of your form and make show or hide it based on your needs.
It will be easier than disabling each form inputs and buttons. Also the overlay is not the component but your div.

Comment: But I do need to show the information inside it ;). And the values are also handled by the component.

Comment: I could not understand your point here. What is the connection between showing the values and disabling it. I am saying you to render your component and at the same level, where the component is inserted, have one more div to mask the page.

Answer (score 0):

I able to read the DOM Nodes present in the child component from the parent Component using ViewChild() https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edmyur?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I see another problem. AfterViewChecked gets called multiple times...

I found the answer myself. The problem is the LifeCycleHook. AfterViewInit works for your own component, but it doesn't wait for the child components to finish rendering.

When I use AfterViewChecked it works!

However I am still puzzled, that logging the nativeElement has always given me the correct DOM, even though it's still not rendered.